# Best Computer For ~$600

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for a laptop that costs around $600 CAD. The functionality of this laptop would be coding and the occasional gaming (minecraft). It would also be nice that it's good for school, but that's not the main priority. While GPU isn't necessary, if there is a decent one that can come with the laptop at that price, send it my way, others not needed. I also need a really good battery, I'm looking for 8h without charge atleast. If you have any suggestions for this budget and these use cases, let me know. Also in case it helps, I plan to dual boot it with Ubuntu but that's not super relevant

Comment: $600 is often too low of a price to get a laptop that can actually be used for "gaming". You should clarify what games you hope to play on it. (Edit the question, don't reply in comments)

Comment: The battery thing is impossible, 8 hours is not realistic even with current, high-end laptops (except in their marketing). If you can release the battery expectation, then you can do this: 1. buy a repairable, but broken laptop (for example, one with a broken display) 2. live with the damage together, until you won't have the cash to fix it (like using the laptop with an external monitor). | So you can get even a quite good laptop for cheap price. Of course your final cost won't be much lesser, but so you will be able to get the laptop *now* and repair it when you will have the money.

Comment: (I have just bought a $300 phone with a broken display for $70. I works well, but the display is broken. So I bought a new display for $30, after checking some youtube videos about the display replacement. Actually, utilizing the lazyness of others is your largest cash provider)